# Spring boot unmarshal xml with list of lists fails

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I have been stuck with this problem for over a week now, I'm trying to unmarshal the application/xml in the @RequestBody of my Spring Boot endpoint to a POJO. The list of bars in each foo fails to unmarshal and Foo.bars becomes null. If I change my List of Bars field in Foo to just be a Bar, I get the last bar of each foo. However that Bar instance fails to unmarshal the XmlValue Bar.value. Both b and the order of Foo is unmarshalled correctly.

I have an xml like this:

```
<a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>
        <foo order="1">
            <bar order="11">1</bar>
            <bar order="22">2</bar>
            <bar order="33">3</bar>
        </foo>
        <foo order="2">
            <bar order="44">4</bar>
            <bar order="55">5</bar>
            <bar order="66">6</bar>
        </foo>
    </c>
</a>
```

And the following POJOs to unmarshal them:

Bar.java

```
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Bar {
    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "order")
        Integer number;
    
        @XmlValue
        Integer value;
    
        public Bar() {}
    
        public Bar(int number, int value){
            this.number = number;
            this.value = value;
        }
    
        public Integer getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    
        public void setNumber(Integer number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    
        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    
        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Foo.java

```
    public class Foo {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "order")
        Integer order;
    
        @XmlElement(name = "bar")
        List<Bar> bars;
        
        public Foo() {}
    
        public Foo(int order, List<Bar> bars){
            this.order = order;
            this.bars = bars;
        }
    
        public Integer getOrder() {
            return order;
        }
    
        public void setOrder(Integer order) {
            this.order = order;
        }
    
        public List<Bar> getBars() {
            return bars;
        }
    
        public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
            this.bars = bars;
        }
        
    }
```

Body.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Body {

    Integer b;
    List<Foo> c;

    public Body(){
    }

    public Body(int b, List<Foo> c){

        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public List<Foo> getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(List<Foo> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

And my endpoint:

```
    public Response postData(@RequestBody Body body) {
    ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the `<c>` and `<foo>` XML elements within the `<a>` element
doesn't match the Java code in your `Body` class:

```
List<Foo> c;
```

There are two alternatives ways to fix this issue.

First alternative (the straight-forward way):
In your `Body`class you replace the line above by

```
C c;
```

(and of course change the constructor, getter and setter accordingly).
Furthermore, you need to create another Java class `C`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class C {
    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    List<Foo> foos;

    // constructor, getter, setter (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Or second alternative (much simpler than the above because you don't need to change the class structure):
In your `Body` class you replace your code line by

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "c")
@XmlElement(name = "foo")
List<Foo> c;
```